# dealing with missing values of categorical columns in Python

Tags: python, data-wrangling

When doing data wrangling, How to deal with missing values of categorical columns.

I am a newbie in python and want to learn more and more. I want to clean and tidy up the 'deck' column in "Titanic" dataset, which contain a lot of NaN values.